# javafxpackager installs applications one on top of the other on Windows

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javafx, codenameone

I've used the NetBeans tool to wrap Swing applications with a native installer. However, all applications seem to install to the same destination folder on Windows and it isn't clear to me where to configure this.

I'm assuming the installer accepts a universal unique identifier for potential upgrades to the application that might change its name and that identifier is identical between both installers. I can't seem to find where such an identifier is defined though?

Comment: You are making an installer for which OS ?

Comment: Windows see the last word in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaFX packager determines the install target directory based on the vendor name specified for creating the package. The application name is used as the name for the shortcut to your application.

I assume you are using the JavaFX ant task to create the installer. In that case, you would have a build target setting up the FX task like this:

```
<fx:deploy ... >
    <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="..." />
    <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}" />
    [...]
</fx:deploy>
```

In that case, you would need to set the `${application.vendor}` property to whatever you want as the target directory.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using that directly but rather the NetBeans adaptation that hides it behind some JavaScript. The app seems to get the right title/vendor but when installing on Windows both applications install in the directory of the application I installed first which carries the name of the first application.

Comment: Even though this didn't answer my question I'll award the bounty etc. since this was the best effort.

Comment: I had only used the ant task in NetBeans so far. I've just checked with the NetBeans adaption, unfortunately I didn't manage to build an install package that came even close to the options I set through the ant task properties :-(.